# Done button invisible in IQkeyboardManager library

Tags: ios, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I have used `IQKeyboardManager` library in my app. i installed `IQKeyboardManager` via cocoapods. Done button is not showing up on each keyboard. that is invisible.

here below my code that i have set in `AppDelegate.swift` file.

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = true
```

[image]

Comment: what's the version of your IQKeyboardManager

Comment: follow the tutorial to install this library :https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: i have installed verion 4.0.10

Comment: resolve This issue?.if resolve please give me answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is fixed in latest V4.0.13. Now it is showing Done button above keyboard toolbar

Comment: What about the objective c version.?

Answer (score 3):

just remove your IQkeyBoardManager pod and reinstall it as :

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

It will upgrade it to highest version.

Check this out : 
https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/917

Comment: i install cocoapods pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift' but done button not visible.

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue from library itself and resolved (closed) on 21st-Aug-17.

- [Done button invisible. #929](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/929)

Update your existing [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) library to latest version [v5.0.3](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/releases/tag/v5.0.3)

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is

Change Return Key to Done in property of UITextfiled at which which you want to show Done button.

[image]

Comment: yes exactly. i need done button in tool bar using IQkeyboardManger

Answer (score 0):

I was using `IQKeyboardManager` for Objective C and facing same issue.

I have installed IQKeyboardManager objective C pod using:

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
```

All again working fine now. I am able to see Done, Next and Prev button for iOS 11.